# How to add google_tag script to header with custom environment variables?

Tags: 8, javascript

I'm trying to add Google Tag Manager to the `<head>` of my document.

Unfortunately, the way I'm doing it with an HTML tag render element, the ampersands (&) are being escaped.

```
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('mymodule.config');
  $gtm_id = $config->get('google_tag_manager_id');
  $gtm_auth = $config->get('gtm_auth');
  $gtm_preview = $config->get('gtm_preview');

  /** @var \Drupal\mymodule\AnalyticsUtility $utility */
  $utility = \Drupal::service('mymodule.utility');

  if (!empty($gtm_id) && !empty($gtm_auth) && !empty($gtm_preview) && $utility->isAdminPage() === FALSE) {


    $script = "(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl+ '&gtm_auth={$gtm_auth}&gtm_preview={$gtm_preview}&gtm_cookies_win=x';f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','{$gtm_id}');\n";


    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
      ['#tag' => 'script', '#value' => $script],
      'google_tag_manager',
    ];
  }
}
```

This results in ampersands in the code.

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&amp;l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl+ '&amp;gtm_auth=testrWktRcmjpViiQKW&amp;gtm_preview=env-6&amp;gtm_cookies_win=x';f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-K53TEST');</script>
```

There are two modules with Google Tag Manager and they both add the code using `hook_page_attachments()`.

The recommendation for adding JavaScript is to use an external file; yet, the Google Tag Manager documentation recommends adding the script in `<head>`.

Is there a way to do this with Drupal settings and a javascript file in my custom module? Alternatively, is there a way not to convert the ampersands to HTML entities?

Comment: Can I ask why no Google Tag module? Works great for me.

Comment: I was acting under the erroneous assumption that Google Tag module did a lot more than it does.  Now that I look at it, I think it's exactly what I need.

Comment: I was acting under the erroneous assumption that Google Tag module did a lot more than it does, when it says "allows non-technical stakeholders to manage the analytics for their website ". Now that I look at it, I think it's exactly what I need.  It looks like I'll need to set up a custom module to set up the dataLayer parameters.  There is https://www.drupal.org/project/datalayer, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The recommendation for adding javascript is to use an external file

That is not always the case and it is more of a guideline than a hard rule.

There is a way to do what you ask, but you shouldn't because the [google_tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_tag) module does exactly what you to want to do. It also allows you to include the GTM snippet inline or as a file.

[image: google_tag module's settings]

Comment: Thanks, It turns out I hadn't explored the google_tag module in enough before I tried to just add the script myself.  The google_tag module looks like it will do what I need.

Comment: No worries. I learn by doing things myself so I completely understand. If you look at the internals of the google_tag module you can see how they injected the snippet in the head without having the markup converted to html entities.

Comment: Yes, they use a generated file.  It's pretty nifty.